# Как тестировать методы которые не возвращают значения?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Предположим у меня есть следующий класс

```
public class Residue
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int WarehouseId {get;set;}
    public int MaterialAssetId {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<ResidueHistory> Histories {get;set;}

    public Residue()
    {
        this.Histories = new List<ResidueHistory>();
    }
}
```

Мне необходимо добавить метод который будет пересчитывать остатки с  даты переданной в качестве параметра.

В тело класса добавляю новый метод

```
public void RecalculateResidueSince(DateTime since)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Первый же тест который я решил реализовать это выход из метода если свойство `Histories` пустое;

Добавил в решение новый проект UnitTest:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestOfResidueMethods
{    
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_RecalculateResidueForEmptyHistory()
    {        
        var residue = new Residue();
        residue.RecalculateResidueSince(DateTime.Now);
    }    
}
```

и тут у меня ступор а что делать дальше в тестовом методе, если бы это была функция то тогда я бы сверил то что получилось в результате с тем что ожидаю.

Подскажите как тестировать и надо ли писать такие тесты для таких методов?

**UPD:**

после написания этого метода я видоизменил тестируемый метод следующим образом:

```
public void RecalculateResidueSince(DateTime since)
{
    if(!this.Histories.Any())
        return;
}
```

т.е. если фактически остатков нет то соответственно ничего не делать, но  не соображу как проверить это в тесте

Comment: Если у вас есть ничего не возвращающий функционал, то он либо не делает никаких изменений вообще, либо существует ради side effects. Соответственно вам и нужно проконтролировать появление ожидаемых side effects.

Comment: @Etki обновил вопрос

Comment: @Bald: Комментарий @Etki всё ещё является ответом на вопрос. Вы не должны тестировать внутреннюю логику функции, только её _результат_.`

Comment: @VladD в текущей реализации метод не делает изменений, в дальнейшем я смогу проверять результат на основании коллекции `Histories`, на текущем же этапе у меня есть два возможных варианта: в случае если `Histories` не содержит данные то тогда либо надо просто выйти из метода ничего не делая иначе выкинуть исключение. исключение мне кажется здесь не нужно так как остатков может не быть

Comment: @Bald: Вы должны составить формальную спецификацию метода (что должно быть на входе, и что на выходе), и проверять именно её. Проверка того, _как именно_ нужный эффект достигается, лишена смысла. Если `Histories` — внутренняя подробность имплементации, то и проверять эффекты, оказанные на неё, не надо. А если часть официального фасада класса, то наоборот надо.

Comment: @VladD не могли бы Вы объяснить что следует понимать под *официальным фасадом класса*?

Comment: @VladD строго говоря, лишена-не лишена зависит от парадигмы тестирования и конкретного кейса (если мы проверяем поведение условного менеджера нотификаций, то у нас нет выбора кроме как подсунуть мок API, которое он дергает, равно как и с throttle/debounce).

Comment: @Bald: То, что вы пишете в документации на этот класс. Всё то, что важно для _пользователей_ этого класса (а не разработчиков).

Comment: @Etki: Я к тому, что тестировать нужно только на соответствие документации. Тестировать работу с внутренним кешем как-то неправильно, это деталь имплементации. (А я подозреваю, что `Histories` и есть такой внутренний кеш.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

В тестах тестируются не возвращаемые значения и не реализация методов, а *контракт*. Контракт -- это некоторые обещания метода о том, что он сделает. Т.е. своеобразный набор пар "вход-выход". Если метод при этом принимает параметры, то количество этих обещаний (пар) может увеличиться и будет зависеть от комбинаций значений параметров.

При этом "выход" может быть разный:

- в виде возвращаемого значения функции
- в виде изменения состояния текущего объекта или других объектов, а также вызова методов в других объектах (зависимостях)

С первым типом контракта все понятно. Получил значение, проверил его.

Во втором типе контракт нужно проверять изменения состояния текущего объекта, а также, если у вас есть зависимости и в тестах вы их мокаете, обращения к этим зависимостям.

---

Контракт вашего метода заключается в следующем (из того, что вы описали в вопросе):

- он пересчитывает остатки, начиная с переданной ему даты, при этом более ранние остатки не изменяются
- если остатков нет, он ничего не делает

Соответственно ваши тесткейсы должны быть следующие:

1. Пустая коллекция остатков. Вызвать метод и проверить, что состояние остатков не изменилось. Как более жесткий вариант: проверить, что состояние всего объекта не изменилось/не было обращений к зависмостям. (Но это уже на грани и попахивает паранойей, хотя в каких-то случаях может быть и оправдано.)
2. Непустая коллекция остатков за разные даты. Вызвать метод за дату, которая больше максимальной даты в остатках. Проверить, что состояние остатков/всего объекта не изменилось.
3. Непустая коллекция остатков. Вызвать метод за дату, которая больше минимальной, но меньше максимальной даты в остатках. Проверить, что остатки с меньшей датой не изменились и что остатки с большей датой изменились корректно.

Comment: т.е. в данном случае после вызова метода мне достаточно проверить что коллекция `Histories` не изменилась?!

Comment: @Bald да. Как более жесткий вариант -- проверить, что состояние *всего* объекта не изменилось и не были вызваны зависимости (если они у вас есть и вы их мокаете).

Comment: А разве *В тестах тестируются не возвращаемые значения и не реализация методов, а контракт. Контракт -- это некоторые обещания метода о том, что он сделает.* это не тоже самое что проверка результата работы метода и тем самым проверка реализации метода, но только другими словами. у нас же есть исходные данные, мы знаем что должно получиться в итоге?!

Comment: @Bald, если у тебя входные данные 2 и 2 и на выходе должно получиться 4, то тебе не важно будет внутри метода 2+2 или 2*2

Comment: @Grundy все дошло. да мне не важно *как именно* это реализовано, я имел ввиду что реализация метода дает **ожидаемый результат**

Comment: @Bald нет, не то же самое. Один и тот же результат может быть достигнут несколькими реализациями. Реализация -- это внутренность класса. Контракт -- это то, что торчит наружу. Мы не должны при тестировании лезть во внутренности, должны пользоваться тем, что доступно снаружи.

Comment: после комментария @Grundy я понял о чем речь: под проверкой реализации я подразумевал что выходные данные соответствуют тому что ожидается, а не то как это делается

Answer (score 3):

Тут можно проверять две вещи:

1. ожидаемое состояние (своего класса или параметра (мокабельно), который внутрь передается)
2. выбрасываемые исключения (только негативный сценарий)

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил начальную реализацию метода. в данном случае я не хочу бросать исключение так как отсутствие остатков в данном случае ожидаемо и я хочу просто выйти из метода, и если не сложно то как можно проверить в методе *выбрасываемое* методом исключение

Comment: @Bald Читайте доку по вашему тест-сьюту. Это может быть в виде аттрибута, вроде [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]

Comment: огромное спасибо за подсказку что возвращаемое исключение может быть определено атрибутом