# Как узнать тип свойства класса, если оно обозначено модификатором доступа private

Tags: c#

Есть класс, в нём есть свойство и конструктор

```
public class Pen
{
    private int inkContainerValue = 1000;

    public Pen(int inkContainerValue)
    {
        this.inkContainerValue = inkContainerValue;
    }
```

в стороннем классе я создаю объект этого класса и хочу узнать какого тип переменная `inkContainerValue` как это реализовать?

Comment: И что вы собираетесь делать с этой информацией?

Comment: @andreycha Unit тест. `Assert.AreEqual("Тип переменной которое мы получим","Предполагаемый тип переменной"`

Comment: @andreycha пытался сделать как-то так 
`Pen pen = new Pen(inkContainerValueTes);
            Type myType = typeof(Pen);
            PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty("inkContainerValue");
            //assert
            Assert.AreEqual(myPropInfo.Name, actual);`, но видимо не совсем понял как `PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty("inkContainerValue");` работает

Comment: И какова цель такого теста? Тестировать нужно [контракты, а не реализацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562065/106).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы делаете почти правильно. Вот такой код получает нужный вам тип:

```
var classType = typeof(Pen);
var field = classType.GetField(
                "inkContainerValue",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var fieldType = field.FieldType;
```

Вам нужно было работать с `GetField` (т. к. `inkContainerValue` — это поле, а не свойство), и указать флаги, разрешающие рефлексию приватных полей.

---

Тем не менее, присоединяюсь к комментарию @andreycha: скорее всего вам это не нужно.

Comment: спасибо большое. всё понял.

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич: Пожалуйста!

Comment: опыта в юнит тестировании мало. Как рационально тестировать поля? Скорее даже не рационально, а правильно ?

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич: Моя точка зрения — никак. Вы должны тестировать лишь то, что есть в спецификации. А в спецификации не могут быть значения полей, в ней может быть лишь наблюдаемое поведение класса.